# Unable to access created_at and updated_at date in laravel with mongodb

Tags: laravel-5

I am having trouble accessing `created_at` and `updated_at` properties in a Laravel model using MongoDB. My date format in the database is as follows:

```
"created_at" : {
    "sec" : NumberInt(1475126325), 
    "usec" : NumberInt(840000)
}, 
"updated_at" : {
    "sec" : NumberInt(1475126325), 
    "usec" : NumberInt(840000)
},
```

I get the following result from MongoDB query:

```
App\Modules\Admin\Models\Segment Object
(
    [table:protected] => tbl_segment
    [timestamps] => 1
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => created_at
            [2] => updated_at
        )

    [collection:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => _id
    [parentRelation:protected] => 
    [connection:protected] => 
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 57ecbefe15285745ba039871
                )

            [created_at] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 1475133182
                    [usec] => 832000
                )

            [updated_at] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 1475133182
                    [usec] => 832000
                )

        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 57ecbefe15285745ba039871
                )

            [created_at] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 1475133182
                    [usec] => 832000
                )

            [updated_at] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 1475133182
                    [usec] => 832000
                )

        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [morphClass:protected] => 
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
)
```

When I try to access `created_at` date, I get the following error:

> **ErrorException in Model.php line 2983:**
>   preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue after updating laravel package (jessengers) for mongodb.You can try - Find following lines

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/', $value)) {
```

in Model.php found at **`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`** 
and replace it by

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/', $value['sec'])) {
```

in **`vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php`** replace **`createFromFormat()`** function with -

```
public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null)
    {
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , $time['sec']);

        if ($tz !== null) {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time, static::safeCreateDateTimeZone($tz));
        } else {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);
        }

        if ($dt instanceof DateTime) {
            return static::instance($dt);
        }

        $errors = static::getLastErrors();
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $errors['errors']));
    }
```

**Note :-** There could be better solution for this , so if anybody else found its alternative then please share.